# how to recover remote branch git?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-bash

Someone has accidentally deleted alpha branch in my team.

I have remote branch origin/alpha. I am not able to find this origin/alpha branch using git ls-remote.

I know last I did commit was XYZ on origin/alpha branch. I have SHA of that branch.

I am trying to create a new branch using this SHA. I used git checkout 45430f8834b0ebda6e89668cc4a4ba3f6a2067a4.

after that I tried to check out new branch using git checkout -b [NEW_BRANCH]

I am trying to git pull this branch. but I am getting below error

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> alpha_recovered
```

Any idea how can I recover my remote branch  which I am not able to see in git ls-remote.

Comment: You have either to run `git checkout -b` in the first place, or name branch with `git branch`.

Comment: I have already named it but after naming it... if I do git pull I am getting below error.

Comment: Yes, you have to link your local branch to remote one. last line in the cited text shows what you need.

Comment: the `ls-remote` command actually goes to remote and checks there to discover what you already know, i.e. that it's gone from there. However You already have locally the 'remote tracking branch' origin/alpha, so simply check that out `checkout -b NewAlpha origin/alpha` and now you have it 'front of house' and can push it to the remote replace the missing 'alpha'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you were tracking the branch, just push that:

```
git push origin origin/alpha:refs/heads/alpha
```

The odd syntax is necessary because push's heuristics for filling out the spelling of refnames are ... maybe just appropriately careful about guessing what you wanted to do to a remote repo.  I'm on the fence about that call myself, but regardless, `origin/alpha` resolves to your repo's `refs/remotes/origin/alpha` ref, the conventional tracking ref for origin's `refs/heads/alpha`, but push isn't set up to make resetting a remote branch to something unusual like that an easy thing to do.  Fair enough I suppose, as it's not a common operation, so perhaps it's best that it forces the full spelling of the target ref on the remote here.

edit: since you have the sha, you could also

```
git push origin 45430f8834b0ebda6e89668cc4a4ba3f6a2067a4:refs/heads/alpha
```

Comment: Note that if your own `origin/alpha` resolves to `45430f8...`, the two commands will do the same thing. Aside from a bunch of special case magic (looking up whether a name is a branch or a tag automatically), `git push <local-name>:<remote-name>` and `git push <id>:<remote-name>` mean the same thing.